# Package BlackBerry App using Cordova 2.7.0

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I've have created an HTML5 app using Cordova 2.7.0.
All is working well with IOS and Android, but not Blackberry. I have googled/self troubleshoot the issue to death, but no dice...

Firstly my issue:
Whenever I try run the app on the simulator with the command (from the app location C:....):

> ant blackberry build

It will successfully build the app see output below:

> Buildfile: C:\SourceCode\App\BlackBerry\build.xml
>
> blackberry:
>
> build:
>
> generate-cod-name:
>        [echo] Generated name: cordovaExample.cod
>
> clean:    [delete] Deleting directory
>   C:\SourceCode\App\BlackBerry\build
>
> package-app:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\SourceCode\App\BlackBerry\build\widget
>        [copy] Copying 22 files to C:\SourceCode\App\BlackBerry\build\widget
>         [zip] Building zip: C:\SourceCode\App\BlackBerry\build\cordovaExample.zip
>
> build:
>        [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing command line options
>        [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing bbwp.properties
>        [exec] [INFO]                      Validating application archive
>        [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing config.xml
>        [exec] [INFO]                      Populating application source
>        [exec] [INFO]                      Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks applicatio n
>        [exec] [FATAL]                     Executable name has embedded quote, spli t the arguments
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 13 seconds

However the app does not appear anywhere on the simulator. Also, in the build folder there are only 2 directories, "widget" and "cordovaExample.zip". I read somewhere there should be a "StandardInstall" and "OTAInstall" folder as well.
In neither of them are any .jad or .cod files.
I have also installed my code signing keys.

When trying to manually build the package (to get .jad or .cod files to install on my device) like so:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK
>   2.3.1.5\bin>ja va -jar bbwp.jar C:\SourceCode\App\BlackBerry\build\cordovaExample.zip -g >*myPassword* -o C:\SourceCode\App\BlackBerry\build\signed

I get the following output:

> [INFO]                  Parsing command line options [INFO]
>   Parsing bbwp.properties [INFO]                  Validating application
>   archive [INFO]                  Parsing config.xml [INFO]
>   Populating application source [INFO]                  Compiling
>   BlackBerry WebWorks application [FATAL]                 Executable
>   name has embedded quote, split the arguments

My IDE: Windows 7 64 bit,
java version "1.7.0_21" (32 bit),
javac 1.7.0_21,
BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.0

I hope I supplied enough info to the issue. Please can you guys give me some help to get this up and running on the simulator and to get a distribution package?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just for in case somebody else ever gets this issue, I got this sorted by uninstalling all Java versions and re-installing Java SDK 6 Update 43 (32 bit - as only this will work with the Blackberry Webworks SDK).